# YAHOO object error with https site in drupal 6

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal-6, yui, yahoo

Please look into below line of js code. It can able to get YAHOO object and works fine in Dev and Test websites but not in production.

The only difference between these three sites is `SSL`. The Dave and Test are 'http' and the Prod is `https`.

```
YAHOO.util.Event.onContentReady("productsandservices", function () {}
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: what errors are thrown? Some basic troubleshooting information would help.

Comment: When debug I am seeing following Error in console: Uncaught ReferenceError: YAHOO is not defined

Comment: Yes all files are loading fine.

Comment: Where is the YAHOO object referenced from? Maybe the js file is not loaded because it's a mixed active content. @user3133448

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go!

https://www.drupal.org/project/yuimenu

IMPORTANT NOTE
Please use YUI 1.1-1 release & YUI MENU 1.1-1 release for production sites.

YUI Menu

NOTE: This module depends on the YUI module.